# Copying formatted text into clipboard

Tags: c#, clipboard, clipboard-interaction

I have strange problem with coping text into clipboard. I want to copy text from textbox with additional formatting. In order to do that I intercept KeyDown event on textbox and I check if keys CTRL and C are pressed. Then I do sth like that

```
 string extraFormatedText = formatText(txtBox.Text);
 Clipboard.SetText(extraFormatedText, TextDataFormat.Text);
```

Function formatText adds couple of empty additional lines in text. However if I paste this text into notepad there is no additional formatting.
Why is that ??

If I call function `Clipboard.GetText()` I can clearly see that in returned string there are extra characters ( \n \r).

Comment: WinForms or WPF? Makes a difference for the KeyDown.

Answer (score 1):

`\r` represents a carriage return and `\n` a [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (linefeed) character.

The method `formatText` must be adding these to the end of the string.

Also, the program Notepad has no formatting functionality such as bold or italic, it simply displays everything in the chosen font, size and style.

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding just \n to insert new lines Notepad will not understand that as it expects \r\n as a line break. Try pasting your text into Notepad++ and you'll see that line breaks are actually there.

It's safer to use Environment.NewLine, which on Windows will give you exactly \r\n.